# I can't resize the columns size as I want

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a layout like looks something like this:

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/431765357200670720/635526422882025496/ae809b5e08198bfc58c223576c3826e9.png?width=356&height=702

Right now, the result I'm having is this one:

https://i.gyazo.com/af20c9fc17b14e3afaf1207691569f72.png

I can't post images because I don't have 10 reputation, sorry for the links :(

The code of the application is this one:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body:Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/steph.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 275),
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                        height: 325,
                        width: 336,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image:DecorationImage(                  
                                image: AssetImage('assets/images/whitebox.jpg'),
                                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40.0)),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              child:Center(
                                child: Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:18,bottom: 160),
                                  height: 80,
                                  width: 300,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    image:DecorationImage(                  
                                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/blackbox.jpg'),
                                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                    ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
                                  ),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "#30 | STEPHEN CURRY",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 26,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 120),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Expanded(
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: Center(
                                              child: Text(
                                                "36",
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Expanded(
                                              flex: 1,
                                              child: Center(
                                                child: Text(
                                                  "Points",
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Expanded(
                                              flex: 1,
                                              child: Center(
                                                child: Text(
                                                  "36",
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Expanded(
                                              flex: 1,
                                              child: Center(
                                                child: Text(
                                                  "Points",
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            flex: 1,
                                            child: Center(
                                              child: Text(
                                                "36",
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                )
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried changin the Expanded widgets for paddings and Containers but it didn't help. Sorry for the silly question, I'm pretty new in flutter, but you know how could I resize the columns to be similar of the first image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created something similar to your expected one. i hope that this code help you to achieve your exact ui.

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body:Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/bg.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 100.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/bg.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                ),
              ),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20.0,
                  ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("2",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),),
                        Text("abc",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),)
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20.0,
                      ),
                    Container(
                      width: 4.0,
                      height: 60.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )
                    ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20.0,
                  ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("2",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),),
                        Text("abc",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),)
                      ],
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 200.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/bg.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                ),
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("2",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),),
                      Text("abc",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),),
                      SizedBox(height: 30.0,),
                      Text("2",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),),
                      Text("abc",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),)
                    ],
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Container(
                        width: 4.0,
                        height: 150.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("2",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),),
                      Text("abc",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),),
                      SizedBox(height: 30.0,),
                      Text("2",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),),
                      Text("abc",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),)
                    ],
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Container(
                        width: 4.0,
                        height: 150.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("2",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),),
                      Text("abc",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),),
                      SizedBox(height: 30.0,),
                      Text("2",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),),
                      Text("abc",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),)
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for! I can't thank you in off and you're now a person to admire.